# How do I reference a controller from within the object it created?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multithreading, asynchronous

So I have a PanelController which is a NSWindowController, and it instantiates an object called FileUploader.  But inside of FileUploader, I want to be able to update some text on the Panel informing the user of the progress that has been made so far.  But I don't know how to reference PanelController given that I can't instantiate a new one.

Am I supposed to use ApplicationDelegate as the go-between, and if so how do I reference that?  If so, do I need ApplicationDelegate to instantiate both PanelController and FileUploader, but then I still don't understand how to reference the ApplicationDelegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also consider using blocks which is another more modern apple approach to callbacks.  Apple is using it more and more in their new APIs.

Here's a specific SO on updating UI and also making it async:

[GCD, Threads, Program Flow and UI Updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290931/gcd-threads-program-flow-and-ui-updating/7291056#7291056)

Here's another SO article on blocks & delegates as callbacks

[How to simplify callback logic with a Block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824038/how-to-simplify-callback-logic-with-a-block)

Comment: Blocks are a great solution to this problem.

Comment: Yeah, I'd vote for blocks as well. Together with GCD they're great for async programming.

Answer (score 3):

Apple recommends using **Delegates** in such scenarios.

Here are some SO answers on how to make delegates:

1. [How Do I Create Delegates in Obj-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)
2. [How Does Delegate Work in Obj-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045803/how-does-a-delegate-work-in-objective-c)