# Cocoa: run block after animation on OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm using animator to implement an animation, like

```
[[self.view animator] setFrame:newFrame];
```

but I want to run a method or block after the animation finish, as follow:

```
[[self.view animator] setFrame:newFrame onComplete:^{
    NSLog(@"****");
}];
```

Is there any way to implement it?

Comment: Maybe [this][1] can helps you, you should write a callback method. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824038/how-to-simplify-callback-logic-with-a-block

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use `NSAnimationContext` and it's `completionHandler`:

```
[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setCompletionHandler:^{
    NSLog(@"****");
}];
[[self.view animator] setFrame:newFrame];
[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

Comment: I think you should set the completion handler before performing the animation.

Comment: @Samir can't find any confirmation in docs, but I think you're right. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Dmitry check the doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSAnimationContext_class/Introduction/Introduction.html). It has all what you need about dealing NSAnimationContext.

Comment: Confirming that if you don't set the completion handler **before** performing the animation (i.e. using _animator_) then your completion handler is called too early.

Answer (score 1):

I find another solution from WWDC video and hope the bellow code helps someone else

[image]