# How to animate coordinate property of MKAnnotation-based annotation on OSX?

Tags: macos, animation, mapkit, mkannotation

It is very easy to animate annotation's coordinate on iOS using the following method:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                 animations:^(void){
                     annotation.coordinate = ...
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)completion{
                     NSLog(@"Animation complete");
                 }
```

However on OSX equivalent method `+[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:]` does not work for me - annotation jumps to new location and calls completion handler immediately i.e. it does not last 10 seconds as expected:

```
[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
    context.duration = 10;

    annotation.coordinate = destination;
} completionHandler:^{
    NSLog(@"Animation complete");
}];
```

I am new to OSX that's why I guess I'm missing something simple here to make this animation work. One guess I have is that @coordinate property is not animatable on OSX MKMapView's annotations but that would make a really strange difference in implementations of MapKit on iOS and OSX.

I created [simple test application](https://github.com/stanislaw/Examples/tree/20150627-osx-animate-mkannotation) to isolate this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. I needed to add `allowsImplicitAnimation = YES` to the code:

```
[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
    context.duration = 10;
    context.allowsImplicitAnimation = YES;

    annotation.coordinate = destination;
} completionHandler:^{
    NSLog(@"Animation complete");
}];
```

I found this hint in screenshot from WWDC session in topic: [Cocoa: run block after animation on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12311331/598057).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Stanislav, allowsImplicitAnimation was the missing key for me as well. For reference, here's my **Swift 4.1** code for animating an MKMapView with custom duration:

```
extension MKMapView {
    func animateTo(region: MKCoordinateRegion, duration: TimeInterval) {
        NSAnimationContext.current.allowsImplicitAnimation = true
        NSAnimationContext.current.duration = duration

        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ _ in
            self.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }, completionHandler:{
            print("Animation complete.")
        })
    }
}
```