# iOS/Objective-C: How can I mix delegation and blocks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, objective-c-blocks

I have two classes. `Delegator` uses delegation to send its result. `Blocker` uses blocks in static methods.

Without changing `Delegator`, how can I **elegantly and easily** implement `methodWithBlock` so that the block is called with the result produced by `methodWithDelegate`?

**Delegator:**

```
@class Delegator;

@protocol Delegate <NSObject>
- (void)delegator:(Delegator *)sender producedResult:(int)result;
@end

@interface Delegator : NSObject
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <Delegate> delegate;
- (void)methodWithDelegate;
@end

@implementation Delegator
- (void)methodWithDelegate
{
    // Some asynchronous computation resulting in
    [self.delegate delegator:self producedResult:42];
}
@end
```

**Blocker:**

```
@interface Blocker : NSObject
+ (void)methodWithBlock:(void(^)(int result))block;
@end

@implementation Blocker
+ (void)methodWithBlock:(void(^)(int result))block
{
    // How to call Delegator's methodWithDelegate and return
    // the result using block ?
    ...
}
@end
```

**Explored solutions:**

- Wrap `Delegator` into a new class or a category and create a method returning a block, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824038/how-to-simplify-callback-logic-with-a-block#4840931). These solutions work but are far too complicated and time-consuming.
- Make `Blocker` conform to the protocol `Delegate` and keep the block in a property, instantiate it within the method `methodWithBlock`, and call the block when the delegation method is called. This does not work, as there is no strong pointer to this new instance and it gets destroyed.
- In the previous solution, to avoid losing the instance by lack of a strong pointer, keep a static array of the current instances of `Blocker` and delete them in the delegate callback method. Again, this solution works but is too complicated.

Comment: I'm not sure you can avoid complications in this case. I'd go with number 3, if it's implemented right it should be a winner. Don't be afraid of complicated things :)

Comment: It's not really clear what result you're returning from `-methodWithDelegate` since everything in your example code returns `void`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that I understand the question, but I'm pretty sure I could help you out if I did. Blocker uses static functions that calculate things and then send the result through a block. You call these functions like this: [Blocker methodWithBlock:^(int result) { ... do whatever with result ... }];, what seems to be the problem? What reference are you losing?

Comment: @Ismael: I am trying to implement the methodWithBlock method.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than delegates and block properties, use an observable property to communicate results. It's cleaner (and easier) as the working object does not have to worry its pretty little head about who may be watching it. And the watching objects don't have to worry about conforming to any special protocol.

Comment: Yes. Apple seems to be moving in that direction to communicate state in objects like NSOperationQueue and reserving delegation for when you actually want to step in and change/extend functionality without subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

The elegant and easy solution is to just add a block-based method to your `Delegator` (e.g. through a category). I know you said you can't do that, but we have to admit, then, that any other block based solution where you're creating new classes to yield the effect you want fails the elegance test.

Having said that, if you desperately need block-based methods and cannot extend `Delegator`, then I'd lean towards option 2, except rather than making those class methods, make them instance methods, and have `Blocker` instantiate `Delegator` and define wrapper methods so that classes that would have used `Delegator` can now use `Blocker`, but with `completion` blocks rather than delegate callbacks. And the class that was previously instantiating `Delegator` can now instantiate `Blocker` instead.